# Feature selection with many Time stamp data and Model classification

Tags: machine-learning, time-series

I’ve a data set with many Timestamp features like:

- Employee duty report time
- Employee duty release time
- Employee work start time
- Employee work end time
- etc.

We currently have a Java application that uses this data to tell if it is legal for an employee to work on a given day or not. The work is not continuous, some days employee work only 2 hours and other days they work straight 8 hours based on various shift assignment rules.

We feed 15 days of data to a Java Rule Engine to find out if an employee is legal to work or not. The Java Rule Engine uses many rules like if an employee works 8 hours in a day then the employee must take minimum 12 hours of rest before starting to work again. From the Java Rule Engine I collected all these data into two sets one with legal to work and other is not legal.

Now I want to use logistic regression to feed the data to classify if an employee is legal or not. What is the best approach to select the various timestamp features? Can this data set can be considered as a “time series” model?

Comment: What is it exactly you are trying to predict?

Comment: Using various time stamp features I am trying to predict if an employee is legal to work or not.